# JSON JAX-RS in Java

Tags: java, json, jersey, jax-rs, httpful

I'm using Jersey for a RESTful web service in Java. I'm consuming them from a PHP client. I have it working fine with JSON as follows:

PHP: (using httpful phar)

```
 $uri="http://localhost:8080/YYYYY/rest/common/json";
    $r = \Httpful\Request::post($uri)
    ->body({"name":"MyName"})->send();
    return $r;
```

Java RESTful WS:

```
@POST
@Path(value="json")
@Produces(MediaType.TEXT_HTML)
@Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public String jsonTest(final JaxData data)
{
    System.out.println(data.toString());
    return "this is the name: "+data.name;
}
```

Java binding class:

```
@XmlRootElement
public class JaxData {
    @XmlElement public String name; 
}
```

Now what I want to do is to send the following JSON structure:

```
{
"title":"MyTitle",
"names":[
    {
        "name":"nameOne"
    },
    {
        "name":"nameTwo"
    }
],
"city":"MyCity",
"country": "MyCountry"
    }
```

So as you can see I want to send objects inside objects apart from the primitive types of Java. How can I do this from the Java side? Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Define an object representing the data you want to send. You can make the object arbitrarily deep (each level in your JSON can be mapped to a sub object).

Here's an example to get you started:

```
public class MyBean implements Serializable {
    private String title;
    private List<JaxData> names;
    private String city;
    private String country;

    // Constructors, getters/setters
}

@POST
@Path(value="json")
@Produces(MediaType.TEXT_HTML)
@Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public String jsonTest(final MyBean data) {
    return data.toString();
}
```

Comment: Hi! thx for the answer, You got me wrong, what i need to bind with lvl's is the object im Consuming not the one im producing. So in your example the parameter of the function would be the MyBean Object.

Comment: Ah, gotcha. Ok, I made some minor changes to my answer.

Comment: Agh sorry to bother you more :/ but how would I implement the constructor? THANK YOU SO MUCH

Comment: Constructor - `public MyBean() { super(); }`

Comment: @Alejandro - no problem! If my answer helped you please consider accepting it. Good luck with the rest of the project.